# How to play a local audio file in Twilio?

Tags: node.js, audio, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

## How can I play a local, temp audio file using Twilio < Play>?

According to this blog post, we can store and read temporary data:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/temporary-storage-twilio-functions

I'd like to try to play an audio file that I store locally at /tmp/audio.mp3

```
 await fs.writeFile(path.join(tmp_dir, "audio.mp3"), buffer, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error writing audio file:", err);
      }

      console.timeEnd("main");
      twiml.play(path.join(tmp_dir, "audio.mp3"));
      return callback(null, twiml);
    });
```

I can't afford to upload the audio file to the cloud and use the URL. There has got to be a simple way to serve a local file I create on the fly.

Comment: [Twilio Assets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/assets) _may_ be the way to go here. The alternative is saving your media as [Base64 and then linking to that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784454/8876321).

Comment: I also think assets might be the better solution as you won't need to upload a file with might exceed the max execution time of a Twilio Function. But I guess this code should work. Can you explain what problem you are facing?

Comment: @fdcpp Is there a way to write to Twilio Assets the way I'm writing my file in the question? I checked out the link you sent, and I don't see a way to write an asset on the fly directly from the function.

Also, regarding the Base64 solution. Does this work with Twilio? The answer you linked seems to be for Android media player.

Comment: @IObert This code does not work. The Twiml I am sending is 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Play>/tmp/audio.mp3</Play></Response>`

It is throwing because it can't find the file. I think it needs a public URL?

Comment: For a base64 data string you would just be considering "vanilla" html5 tags. The `<source>` tag or the `src` field would be `data:audio/mp3;base64,<BASE64String>`. I would prototype that with a test tone first (e.g 1 second of 440 Hz) to make sure Twilio is not adding any extra restriction before you do a tone of work. With respect to Twilio Assets, that has been suggested by a few answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65799774/how-to-send-locally-stored-media-files-using-twilio-over-whatsapp-node-js-exp/65799998#65799998 but I am passing that on without testing myself.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Play>/tmp/audio.mp3</Play></Response>` is not containing a valid URL. You need to prefix it with the URL of your Function and make sure the resource is publicly available.

Comment: @IObert How can I make sure that the temp file is publicly available?

Comment: Are they not publicly accessible by default? You can check if with tools like curl once you have the URL.